# Having trouble putting data into a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to coding, so take it easy on me! I recently started a pet project which scrapes data from a table and will create a csv of the data for me. I believe I have successfully pulled the data, but trying to put it into a dataframe returns the error "Shape of passed values is (31719, 1), indices imply (31719, 23)". I have tried looking at the length of my headers and my rows and those numbers are correct, but when I try to put it into a dataframe it appears that it is only pulling one column into the dataframe. Again, I am very new to all of this but would appreciate any help! Code below

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
import requests
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://www.fangraphs.com/leaders.aspx? pos=all&stats=bat&lg=all&qual=0&type=8&season=2018&month=0&season1=2018&ind=0&page=1_1500'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
#pulling table from HTML
Table1 = soup.find('table', id = 'LeaderBoard1_dg1_ctl00')
#finding and filling table columns
headers = []
for i in Table1.find_all('th'):
    title = i.text
    headers.append(title)
#finding and filling table rows
rows = []
for j in Table1.find_all('td'):
    data = j.text
    rows.append(data)
#filling dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns = headers)
#show dataframe
print(df)
```

Comment: This is because the shape of rows and the dataframe is not matched. In the variable `header', there are 23 values meaning that you will make 23 columns. However, the variable 'rows' are just a set of rows with only one column. It would be nice if you provide your sample of expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a dataframe with 692 rows with 23 columns as a new dataframe. However looking at the rows array, you only have 1 dimensional array so shape of passed values is not matching with indices. You are passing 692 x 1 to a dataframe with 692 x 23 which won't work.

If you want to create with the data you have, you should just use:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=headers[1:2])
```

Comment: that fixed it- thank you!

Comment: Please make sure to close your question by accepting an answer so stackoverflow community cann focus on other questions.

Answer (score 0):

Alternativly you can achieve your goal directly by using `pandas.read_html` that processe the data by BeautifulSoup for you:

```
pd.read_html(url, attrs={'id':'LeaderBoard1_dg1_ctl00'}, header=[1])[0].iloc[:-1]
```

- `attrs={'id':'LeaderBoard1_dg1_ctl00'}` selects table by id
- `header=[1]` adjusts the header cause there are multiple headers
- `.iloc[:-1]` removes the table footer with pagination

#### Example

```
import pandas as pd

pd.read_html('https://www.fangraphs.com/leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=bat&lg=all&qual=0&type=8&season=2018&month=0&season1=2018&ind=0&page=1_1500',
            attrs={'id':'LeaderBoard1_dg1_ctl00'},
            header=[1])[0]\
            .iloc[:-1]
```